# not creating a release because no files have changed

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I installed the Parse Cloud Code Command Line Tools last August, and was able to update my Cloud Code regularly using "parse deploy" from the Mac OS X Terminal command line.

I am as of today on the latest Parse CLI version 3.0.1

Now today, when I try to add another Parse function to the main.js file in the "cloud" directory, and save the file, and then to a "parse deploy" I get the message "Not creating a release because no files have changed"

Indeed, the Cloud Code on the Parse.com website has not been updated.

What is my problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... "parse deploy" did not work anymore... so I tried "parse develop", and this successfully uploaded the new JavaScript up to Cloud Code.  Thereafter, "parse deploy" worked.